# c# decode base64 - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: c#

I have problem decode this base64 string, it always return ' Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string'.
But I managed to decode online at 'https://www.base64decode.org/'

These are my codes:

```
string base64Encoded = "eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IndVWUdZWXp5dTJPMzNtVjY1WHFBVzBiTFlMeU5TU2VKZFlGTldKNnpzY0kiLCJ4NXQiOiJ0V3lmNTA0aTM3TXZxN0t1eEVyQTY4VTE4c1kiLCJraWQiOiJTSUdOSU5HX0tFWSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0";

string base64Decoded;

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);

base64Decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: The error message is straightforward: your `base64Encoded` string value is not valid. It's missing the trailing `'='` padding characters. You can add them back by appending the correct number of `=` characters.

Comment: There are 171 chars there @Dai, which is divisible by 3 (57 x 3). So no padding should be required.

Comment: @seesharper if you reencode the decoded string it gives you the padding.

Comment: Ah I see why @Droppy - the actual representation is not 1 character per byte. +1

Comment: It might be worth checking that your base64 isn't one of the [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table), some of which have different characters than the `/` and `+` that `Convert.FromBase64String`. Some variants don't require the `=` padding characters at the end, which is what makes me think that this could be a variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some tests, and according to the comments you should not need the padding, but if you try to encode the decoded string:
`{"x5t#S256":"wUYGYYzyu2O33mV65XqAW0bLYLyNSSeJdYFNWJ6zscI","x5t":"tWyf504i37Mvq7KuxErA68U18sY","kid":"SIGNING_KEY","alg":"RS256"}`

it gives you:
`eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IndVWUdZWXp5dTJPMzNtVjY1WHFBVzBiTFlMeU5TU2VKZFlGTldKNnpzY0kiLCJ4NXQiOiJ0V3lmNTA0aTM3TXZxN0t1eEVyQTY4VTE4c1kiLCJraWQiOiJTSUdOSU5HX0tFWSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0=`

Notice the padding at the end.

Comment: so.. the trick is to add the padding before decode, right? thanks @Droppy